# Jasmine was not injected in my file?

Tags: jasmine, bower, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

After a lot of trouble I got Jasmine working on my Yeoman/Angular setup. Now, when I run `grunt serve`, I see a message that says `Jasmine wasn't injected in your file`. Additionally in my browser console, I see that Jasmine is undefined. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892016/bower-throws-jquery-not-injected-warning-after-running-grunt-serve) issue and [this](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/55) thread. Included the files manually in my `index.html` and `karma.conf.js` but no luck. Besides, after I execute `grunt serve`, those addresses are removed from my index.html file. My bower json too has the entry for jasmine. These are my files:

`karma.conf.js:`

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2014-09-12 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function(config) {
'use strict';

config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '../',

// testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js', 
  'bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core.js',
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js', 
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  //'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js',
  'app/views/*.html'
],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: [
  'PhantomJS'
],

// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-jasmine-jquery',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],

preprocessors: {
    'app/views/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix: 'app/',
    moduleName: 'views'
},

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false,

colors: true,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
// proxies: {
//   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
// },
// URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
// urlRoot: '_karma_'
});
};
```

`bower.json:`

```
{
  "name": "yeosalt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.0",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-touch": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "jasmine-jquery": "~2.0.5",
    "jasmine": "~2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.0",
    "jasmine-jquery": "~2.0.5"
  },
    "appPath": "app"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "Jasmine wasn't injected in your file" is due to your bower.json configuration.

The following lines

```
"jasmine-jquery": "~2.0.5",
"jasmine": "~2.0.4"
```

need to be under "devDependencies" and not "dependencies" because they are only used for test purpose.

If you really want to have them under "dependencies", grunt will warn you that the files are not injected until you specificaly add them in your grunt config.

About the second problem ("jasmine is undefined"), I have also got this problem once.
It seems that there was a problem between jasmine version in karma (https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/issues/168).
In my bower.json I have (no jasmine needed) :

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "jasmine-jquery": "~1.3.1"
},
```

In my karma.conf.js, I have at the top of files config :

```
files: [
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
    // ...
]
```

And then I was able to use jasmine variable.

Hope that will help you.